# Make multiple variations from 1 master file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, master-page

I'm making business cards in photoshop and want to have multiple variations of the same "base". For example let's assume we have something like this:

[image]

We want this to be our Master File.
Child files would be able to for example edit the colour of a pane or edit the IMAGE. But when the position of something is changed in the master file, it's changed in the child files as well. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing, [but business cards can be made in pohotoshop with this method](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/35241/2332). Not that I'd recommend PS for making business cards.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant set up master/child files in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all elements as Illustrator *reference images* that you *place* on a pane. And you could record an action to generate the file and place the refs for you.

### Record (PS Action)

1. Hit Record
2. Generate desired size
3. Import/Place AI ref
4. Generate one color overlay (generate them from the layer palettes bottom action drop downs) for each ref.
5. Move the overlay above each ref
6. Hold the Alt key and move the cursor between the overlay and the ref until you get a "marriage" type icon (two circles) and click. This binds the color overlay to the ref.
7. Hit Stop

Now you have an action that you can repeat as often as you want. Keep in mind that it only will be usable as long as you have the files in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're looking for Photoshop help here, BUT I have to drop InDesign as an option here.

InDesign does everything your asking and MUCH MORE in regards to [Master pages](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/master-pages.html) and applying [styles](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/paragraph-character-styles.html) over multiple pages/layouts. PLUS InDesign is a better layout tool then photoshop can ever be (Especially for print).

A very simple tut: [How to create and print business cards](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/create-print-business-cards.html)